# Flask-Nav Bootstrap navbar, dynamic construction: Align some element to the right side

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications, flask

I am currently creating a WebApp based on Flask, Bootstrap and the Flask-Nav extension.
I created a dynamic navigation bar, which works just fine:

```
#custom navbar
def dynamic_navbar():
    navbar = Navbar(title='navbar_titel')
    navbar.items = [View('FirstPage', 'first_page')]   
    navbar.items.append(
    Subgroup('Dropdown1',
        View('Sub1', 'sub1_page'),
        View('Sub2', 'sub2_page'),
        View('Sub3', 'sub3_page')
                    )
            )       
    navbar.items.append(View('SecondPage', 'second_page'))
    return navbar

#register navbar to app    
nav.register_element('top', dynamic_navbar)
```

I also changed the default BootstrapRenderer so i can easily change the navbar bootstrap template

```
#Coustom Navbar Renderer to render after certain bootstrap navbars templates

class CustomRenderer(BootstrapRenderer):
    def visit_Navbar(self, node):
        nav_tag = super(CustomRenderer, self).visit_Navbar(node)
        nav_tag['class'] += 'navbar navbar-inverse'
        return nav_tag


#register renderer to app
register_renderer(app, 'custom', CustomRenderer)
```

All this just works fine and I can easily integrate it into my master template as a block by:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
{{nav.top.render(renderer='custom')}}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

So here comes the final problem. I would like to align some, but not all elements inside my navbar to the right instead left (for example: only View(Sub3...). I know how to do this directly in a HTML document, but somehow have difficulties of thinking of an easy way to do this in my Flask App without loosing my dynamic navbar construction or creating many new classes.

Is there an easier way I can change my Renderer or creating a subclass of the View element to do so?